# C++ and for/in (?) loops

Tags: c++

I'm a bit rusty on C++ (still). Will the "getChildren()" function to the right be called every loop?

```
for (Node* node : this->m_stage->getChildren()) {
}
```

On a side note, what would be the name of this kind of loop?

Comment: what prevents you from trying it out?

Comment: I could try it out, but can I assume that it will behave the same with every flavor of C++ and compiler?

Comment: at least it would show some effort from your side

Comment: Asking on SO, and answering comments, is still faster in some cases.

Comment: @Jonny : That's very, very sad.

Answer (score 3):

It's [Range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) introduced from c++11. And `this->m_stage->getChildren()` will be evaluated only once.

> Syntax
>   `attr(optional) for ( range_declaration : range_expression ) loop_statement`
>
> The above syntax produces code equivalent to the following (__range,
>   __begin and __end are for exposition only):
>
> ```
> {
>     auto && __range = range_expression ;
>     for (auto __begin = begin_expr,
>                 __end = end_expr;
>             __begin != __end; ++__begin) {
>         range_declaration = *__begin;
>         loop_statement
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This is a *range-based loop*. No, the expression on the right is evaluated only *once*.

In more detail, a loop of the form `for (T x : expr) body` is roughly equivalent to the following standard for loop:

```
{
    auto && c : expr;
    for (auto it = begin(c), e = end(c); it != e; ++it)
    {
        T x = *it;
        body
    }
}
```

In particular, this means that the range expression (`expr` in my example) can be an rvalue (a temporary value created by a function call). Note that the range expression may also be an array or a braced list.

Answer (score 0):

This is called a *range-based for loop*. Your loop is roughly equivalent to this:

```
{
    auto && __range = this->m_stage->GetChildren() ; 
    for (auto __begin = begin(__range),
         __end = end(__range); 
         __begin != __end; ++__begin) { 
        Node* node = *__begin; 
    } 
}
```

As you can see, `GetChildren` is only called once.